# Extract keys and specific values from a json string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have data in a MySQL table in one table cell that looks like this

```
{ "key1":
  { "otherkey":1,
    "someotherkey": 2,
    "thirdkey": 3
    },
  "key2": 
  { "otherkey":2, 
    "someotherkey": 1, 
    "thirdkey": 0
    }, 
  "key3": 
  { "otherkey":2, 
    "someotherkey": 0, 
    "thirdkey": 2
    }
  }
```

only there are several hundreds of primary keys, and the list of those primary keys is sometimes updated

I need to extract all the "keyN" keys and also all the "thirdkey" values into one table in Grafana. I don't want to manually type all the keys, since it would be a lot of upkeep as they change frequently

The final result should look like this:

| primary key | thirdkey |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | 3 |
| key2 | 0 |
| key3 | 2 |

Unfortunately, I can't change the format of the data, have to work with what I have

I know how to extract specific values with json_extract but can't figure out how to apply it here.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val JSON)
SELECT 1 id, '
{ "key1":
  { "otherkey":1,
    "someotherkey": 2,
    "thirdkey": 3
    },
  "key2": 
  { "otherkey":2, 
    "someotherkey": 1, 
    "thirdkey": 0
    }, 
  "key3": 
  { "otherkey":2, 
    "someotherkey": 0, 
    "thirdkey": 2
    }
  }
' AS val;
```

```
SELECT test.id,
       keys_table.primary_key,
       JSON_EXTRACT(test.val, 
                    CONCAT('$.', 
                           keys_table.primary_key, 
                           '.thirdkey')) thirdkey
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(test.val),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (primary_key VARCHAR(64) PATH '$')) keys_table
```

| id | primary_key | thirdkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | key1 | 3 |
| 1 | key2 | 0 |
| 1 | key3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6tKf_Jet)